# Spotfire, Bar chart, adding a reference line with description

Tags: bar-chart, spotfire, horizontal-line

I wanted to put a description that reads, "Coal emits 2x more CO2 than Natural Gas".

[image: Here is the Screenshot]

But as you can see, it was cut in the middle.

How can I show it fully? & How do I place it in the middle, as if I would place a line in the middle of the page a MS Word?

I know that I can show the hidden words if I make the graph lager, but I want to know if there is any other way that I can do it. Thanks

Comment: What version of Spotfire?

Comment: @scsimon its 7.8.0. Can you help

Comment: Have you tried just making an annotation?